# jQuery UI CSS reset

Tags: css, jquery-ui, less, jquery-ui-datepicker, reset

I'm implementing a booking process into an already excising WP website. The website has a MailChimp plugin that uses jQuery UI and has a theme designated for that, this part is out of my hands to remove or change. 
This affects my code in the booking process by overwriting my custom css (less) for jQuery Datepicker.

My question is how can I reset all the jQuery UI components that have a specific ancestor class (.odin)? So that only components below that class will be reset.

br.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must overwrite the css, as seems to be your case, simply use a higher specificity. Get your selectors from your element inspector of choice and add the added specificity of your wrapper class. .odin .datepicker td{ /* your rule */ }

Comment: thanks guys. I guess i'll just have to css my way above the other files. I was just fishing if there would be any other way. ;)

Comment: If you have no control over it, probably not. The element itself ought to have a css folder that you could modify, but I'm not sure how you would create a child to the plugin in wordpress so that your changes aren't canceled out with a plugin update.

Answer (score 0):

.odin {
*
}

this is called clear hack, its not a good practice to do it. Check alternatives first.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your problem lies not in jQuery but in CSS. You need to have better, more specific css selectors which do not end up getting beaten out by the jQuery UI rules.

I find using this [calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) helps!